# Need assistance pulling country cc from functions file

Tags: php, function

I have the following code that checks a country database by IP. It works when I use the following.

```
$userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
if ($userInfo->country->isoCode == 'US')
echo 'Hallo! Schön dass Sie hier sind!';
```

Now, I want to place this in my functions file to return only the country code as lowerstring, then I can reference it throughout the site.

So in this situation it will return "us" and not "US".

Apologies if this seems like an easy question, I'm a newbie.

Thanks.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function getCountryCode() 
{
    $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
    return strtolower($userInfo->country->isoCode);
}
```

Going further you can check whether `$userInfo->country->isoCode` has any value.

```
function getCountryCode() 
{
    $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
    if (!empty($userInfo->country->isoCode)) {
        return strtolower($userInfo->country->isoCode);
    } else {
        return '';   // or some default country code
    }
}
```